# deleting specific word in python

Tags: python

I have practice question which I struggled with I'm gonna put the question and the code I tried Thanks all(Im new)

> Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged.

MY code:

```
def not_string(str):
  return 'not' + ' ' +  str
  if str == 'not' :
    return str
```

Comment: try startswith() combined with lower()

Comment: You can try f-strings for simple string formatting, 
f"{'' if string.lower().startswith('not ') else 'not '}string"

Comment: Thanks guys I look for the starts with function and I learned it

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't call your variable `str` because you shadow the builtin [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str). (And here my solution with an f-string: `f"{['not ', ''][value.startswith('not')]}{value}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible piece of code:

```
def not_string(s):
    if s.startswith('not'):
        return s
    return 'not ' + s
```

You can also use a one liner:

```
def not_string(s):
    return s if s.startswith('not') else 'not ' + s
```

If you do not want to use built-in functions then you might want to try something like this:

```
def not_string(s):
    if s[:3] == 'not':
        return s
    return 'not ' + s
```

Comment: Thanks so much man I appreciate it.... I couldn't understand the second line of the 3rd code  why we used the Len function and the str[:3] can you explain on your spare time

Comment: It check if the length of the string input have more than 3 to chars, if it's possible for having "not" in the input string. After that iterate over the first 3 chars and compare that to "not" (to check if have "not" in the start)

Comment: 2 notes: you don't need to check the length of the string before taking a slice like `[:3]`, Python will return a shorter slice if the string is too short. Also, you should avoid using `str` as a variable name, as it is the name of a Python builtin, and doing so shadows the original meaning.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You're totally right, thanks for pointing it out, I updated the answer with the details you provided

Comment: Thanks guys the function was defined already I'm practicing on codingbat

Answer (score 2):

Your code have return in the first line of the function, so the rest is never reached. The first line just returns "not" and your string. The second line just checks if the string is "not" (`star == 'not'`) and not check if it starts with "not".

My solution:

```
def not_string(str):
  if str.startswith("not"):
    return str
  return "not " + str
```

First check if start with "not" in the input string

if have, just return it

if not it will return the "not" with the input string

Answer (score 1):

The order of the sentences in your code is important. The first line in the `not_string` function is a `return` statement. As soon as the interpreter execute this order, it exits the function and *returns* (hence the name) to the caller code. This means the rest of the lines if the function are **never** executed.

One solution is to invert the order ot the things you are doing in the function: *first* check if the string needs to be modified (that is to say, it doesn't starts with `not` ). If this is the case, add the `not` at the start of the string. Final step is returning the value:

```
def not_string(str):
    if not str.startswith('not '):
        str = 'not ' + str
    return str
```

Note: Concatenating strings with `+` is the least efficent way to do it, but do not care about this for now.

Answer (score 0):

def not_string(s):
return s if s.startswith('not') else 'not ' + s

Comment: This is just completely irrelevant to the question, which is not about removing words from a text, but about adding one at the start of a single sentence if it doesn't already start with it...

Comment: Sorry I have updated the answer ..realized it is been already answered by @Riccardo Bucco.